# Realm primary key not getting stored

Tags: database, xamarin, realm, primary-key, realm-mobile-platform

Data Model:

```
public class Product : RealmObject
    {
        [PrimaryKey,JsonProperty(PropertyName = "productId")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "parentId")]
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "productType")]
        public string ProductType { get; set; }
    }
```

Method used to add product to db:

```
public void AddSampleProduct(Product product)
        {
            var _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
            using (var transaction = _realm.BeginWrite())
            {
                var entry = _realm.Add(product);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Method used to retrieve product:

```
public Product GetProductById(int id)
        {
            Product product = null;
            var _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
            product = _realm.Find<Product>(id);
            var p = _realm.Find<Product>(id);
            return product;
        }
```

Method to fetch list of products:

```
public List<Product> GetProductList()
        {
            List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
            var _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
            productList = _realm.All<Product>().ToList();
            return productList;
        }
```

Whenever I try to fetch a product using an id it returns null, at the same time if i try to fetch the list am getting all the products but with the primary key property having the value 0 for all the products. Probably the primary key is not getting stored and hence am not able to fetch individual product using id.

Also, in the model class I had tried defining the primary key and Json Property in separate lines like mentioned below.

```
public class Product : RealmObject
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "productId")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "parentId")]
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "productType")]
        public string ProductType { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `primary key property having the value 0` : Are you setting the primary key in your  code anywhere? That is not an auto-incrementing field. Open the realm file in Realm Studio and review the data that is actually stored : https://www.realm.io/products/realm-studio/

Comment: yes am setting the value. we are using newtonsoft to deserialize a json, and the value is set at that time. Had debugged and confirmed that the values are set before passing the same to db.

Comment: What version and platform are you testing on? Also I would look at your realm file with Realm Studio, because if productid was actually was created with PrimaryKey then multiple records with zeros would not be allowed otherwise it should raise needs migration event if it was added later, etc.. Have you tried re-creating the realm file from scratch and manually entering a record for an id of 1 and retrieving them with Find(1), etc..

Comment: I tried adding a single item hardcoding the values as well. same result. The observation is that any property set as primary key is not getting set. If its an int variable then the value is 0 and if we define a string as primary key and then the value getting stored in db is null.

Comment: I tried the same code in another sample project and its working fine there. Will recheck the actual project and update here.

Comment: The same code worked when I removed and added the realm package in the actual project